# Making a Perfect Cusp Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This Cusp I made came out awkward and I can not fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round]
 \tikzset{axes/.style={}}
 % The graphic
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)-- (0,3) node[left] {$y$};
\draw (0.25,0.4) to [out=10,in=80] (1.5,2.5);
\draw (1.5,2.5) to [out=-80, in=175] (2.75,.4);
%%%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Note it is not exactly symmetric either but the head is cleaner.

Comment: What precisely do you want to achieve? (The top is tilted since you have `in=80` and `out=-80` instead of `90`.)

Comment: @Marmot, I posted above what I am trying to achieve, I didn't think I'd have to ask a question on this but I also tried 90 and could not get the look I wanted.

Comment: How about `\draw[thick] (0.25,0.4) to [out=10,in=-90]  (1.5,2.5)
 to [out=-90, in=175] (2.75,.4);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the sign of `80` in `\draw (0.25,0.4) to [out=10,in=80] (1.5,2.5);` is the culprit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round]
 \tikzset{axes/.style={}}
 % The graphic
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)-- (0,3) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[thick] (0.25,0.4) to [out=10,in=-90]  (1.5,2.5)
 to [out=-90, in=175] (2.75,.4);
\draw[thin] (1.5,2.5) -- ++ (0.2,0.6) node[above]{$f'(a)$ does not exist};
\draw (1.5,0.2) -- (1.5,-0.2) node[below]{$a$};
%%%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: marmot, why does it have to be 90? (Side note `$f'(a)$ does not exist`).

Comment: @gusbrs Well, that's how I interpreted "Note it is not exactly symmetric either but the head is cleaner.". I thought the OP wants to have it symmetric. (And thanks for the note!)

Comment: @Marmot, that works but I thought I tried that. Eyes playing tricks on me. Not sure exactly  what we changed Thanks Marmot!

Comment: @MathScholar I guess the sign of `in` in `\draw (0.25,0.4) to [out=10,in=80] (1.5,2.5);` is crucial. I have a `-` there.

Comment: Well, conceptually, we could still have side derivatives (is this how this is said in english?...) reaching "a" at 80 degrees and the derivative in a would not exist. The graphic would be symmetric like this. But the question is why doesn't tikz accept it?

Comment: @Marmot, yes now I see it. All due to a -. Thanks again!

Comment: @gusbrs Ti*k*Z of course accepts it. `90` is not crucial but the sign is. Note, however, if there is a reflection symmetry w.r.t. `a`, it has to be 90. Thanks again for your correction!

Comment: marmot, As the historian in the house, I should never dare into calculus around here. ;) But I do beg to disagree, we could have symmetry with any approaching angle, including zero (e.g. a normal distribution).

Comment: @gusbrs Well, there could be "a" symmetry, but not a reflection symmetry, which tells us that `f(a+x)=f(a-x)`.

Comment: Mmh, I really don't know what you mean by "reflection symmetry" as opposed to "symmetry". Btw, see [Ubiquitous' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462577/105447). (Sorry, I must be off now...)

Comment: @gusbrs Oh, now I see what you mean. Yes, of course you could do that. I thought there was a requirement that `in` and `out` coincide`. If not, yes, you could do `in=-100` and `out=-80`, say. Whether or not this will still be called a cusp, I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `pgfplots` package, which extends `tikz` to include a wide variety of plotting options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,xtick={0.5},xticklabels=$a$,axis lines=left,ymajorticks=false,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,clip=false]
\addplot  [domain=0.1:0.5] {0.1+x^2} node [pos=0.2,above left] {$f$};
\addplot  [domain=0.5:0.9] {0.1+(x-1)^2} node[pin={90: $f'(a)$ does not exist.} ] at (axis cs:0.5,0.35) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ubiquitos Thank you for your answer. I needed a corner with a more vertical right and left tangent, but someone else will find this very useful to them. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution just for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-plot}
\def\f#1{(x-#1)^2+1}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,ticks=none,labels=none](-.4,-.5)(4.5,3.5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-.3,-.4)(4,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot{1}{2}{\f{1}}
\psplot{2}{3}{\f{3}}
\psxTick[labelsep=1pt](2){a}
\rput(2.2,3){\rnode[b]{a}{$f'(a)$ does not exist}}
\pcline[nodesep=2pt]{->}(a)(*2 {\f{1}})
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]